# Windows phone 8 Emulator internet issue with vodafone 3g stick k3772

Tags: networking, hyper-v, internet-connection, windows-phone-8-emulator, windows-phone-8-sdk

Internet is working on all other applications but not on windows phone emulator 8.

i tried deleting the network bridge(from network connections)  and restarting the emulator to make new network bridge, it didn't work.

also i tried to manually add this "Mobile Broadband Connection" to bridge (from network connections) but its not showing the option.

i tried using virtual switch manager to make new virtual network switch for external network namely "vodafone adapter" but there also its not showing the vodafone adapter.

Could it be that vodafone doesn't allow internet sharing or something ?

Any workaround to get my usb stick internet working in my emulator would be helpful.
**Thanks**
*And also the strange thing is internet works in emulator additional tools-location tab but won't work in any of the apps (including internet explorer and bing maps etc. )*

i am using visual studio 2012 professional, sdk 8.0 , windows 8 .
and my emulator internet works fine with other network adapters.

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It could be the problem with IP address.
Check out this thread. This may help you.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wptools/thread/1734dac7-37a4-4d9a-bf89-42b6d493adda/#79292d03-7318-40a9-a92b-101fe0025469

Comment: Sorry, But there is virtual-adapter for that vodafone adapter.